# window.onload not defined - es2015 wants everything to be global

Tags: javascript, global, eslint

I switched to writing in es2015 syntax and using babel as a transpiler. Suddenly this simple function doesn't work anymore, es-lint throws the errors :

> document is not defined
>
> window is not defined

```
const jsLoaderClass = document.getElementsByClassName('js-loader')[0];

// hide logo on pageload
window.onload = function jsLoader() {
  jsLoaderClass.style.display = 'none';
};
```

it only works when I set it to global like this:

```
const jsLoaderClass = global.document.getElementsByClassName('js-loader')[0];

// hide logo on pageload
global.window.onload = function jsLoader() {
  jsLoaderClass.style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: `i just switched to es-2015` - where and how did you make this switch? `global` is undefined in every browser I've tried

Comment: sorry, i meant i started to use eslint with babel, since i am following a book and tutorials that use e6, to transpile the code back to es5, it all works, but eslint throws the error.

Comment: ahh, is there a "switch" in eslint (like there is in jshint) to specify the target environment is a browser?

Comment: i will check it out thanks

Comment: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments seems to be what you want

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the "env" in your eslint config file to "browser".